# android image transparency

Tags: android, image, transparent

Is there a way to load an image file into an ImageView object, and then
define a transparent color for this object ?

Answer (score 1):

try using setalpha property to your drawable...

Refer to this sample

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html

Comment: No, my need is to make certain pixels (all the red pixels for example) transparent.